# How to align "glyphicon" in the drop-down menu in one vertical line

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the drop-down menu for mobile devices, "glyphicon-leaf" is centered, but vertically there is no alignment in one line, as in the case of text (a screen is attached)
http://www.imageup.ru/img69/2884966/123.jpg.html

https://codepen.io/vosolodkiy/pen/XeqaOR
    HTML

```
       <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="index.html" title="Food, LLC"><h1>Food, LLC</h1>
            </a>
       </div>

     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu_collapse" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                    </div>

     <div id="menu_collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul id="menu-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#Chicken" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>Chicken</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Beef" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg ">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>Beef</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#Sushi" class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf"></span>Sushi</a>
          </li>
          </ul>
    </div><!--menu-list-->
    </div><!--container-->
    </nav><!--navigation menu-->
        </header>
      <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
      <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can you post an image showing what you want it to look like? I'm not clear from reading the description and looking at the image.

Comment: Are you wanting the list items centered in the unordered list but to still be lined up by the leaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap the content in a `div` tag with the class `wrap` and give it a fixed width you can vertical align multiple elements relative to each other. I hope this is what you want to achieve. The below CSS classes are changed.

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
  width:120px;
  text-align:left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Below is a working example for the same! Let me know if this fixes your issue!

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @VSolodkiy Can this question be closed?

Comment: Yes,  this question can be closed.